# using webrtc code on my cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webrtc, videochat

Im trying to use webRTC API such as getUserMedia and RTCPeerConnection for my app which is built with the cordova framework.

I am wondering if its possible for webRTC to work on both Android and iOS since my video chat app is a hybrid app (js and html) which is supposed to manage the entire p2p video chat by itself, unlike pc versions which require a web browser for the webRTC communication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to get them to work.  Keep in mind, the architecture of cordova application is reliant on a Web View rendering of your application.  That web view will need to provide the WebRTC APIs to consume in JavaScript.  This [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/88052) suggest the web view in iOS 11 does not support it.  In fact, it is pretty new to Safari all together.  This [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) says that the latest versions of Android Web Views do have support.  WebRTC is a collection of technologies that enables RTC, and there are [native libraries](https://webrtc.org/native-code/) for accomplishing this.  I have seen a couple of plugins for Cordova that enable access to native code so you are not as reliant on the Web View.

[cordova-plugin-iosrtc](https://github.com/BasqueVoIPMafia/cordova-plugin-iosrtc)

[phonertc](https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc)

Good luck!

Comment: Your welcome! It is an awesome technology.  This article may be of some use as well: https://webrtchacks.com/webrtc-hybrid-applications/